# Can not use -w -h in traincascade

Tags: c++, opencv

I have sone problem with size of sample traincascade. I use opencv_traincascade.exe to train rear of car. Size of rear of car which i need to have a size 72x48. Now i use createsample to create 2000 sample size 72x48 with command

```
D:\Project_Android\Classifier\bin\opencv_createsamples.exe  -info positive.txt -bg negative.txt -vec vector.vec -num 2000 -w 72 -h 48
```

Now, i have a vector file and negative.txt (sure negative.txt have absolute direction to background images). i use opencv_traincascade.exe with command.

```
D:\Project_Android\Classifier\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data HaarTraining -vec vector.vec -bg negative.txt -numPos 250 -numNeg 1500 -numStages 10 -nonsym -minhitrate 0.999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -mode ALL -w 72 -h 48 -precalcValBufSize 2046 -precalcIdxBufSize 2046 PAUSE
```

I get an error.

[image]

When i use size 24x24 (-w 24 -h 24) for createsample.exe step and cascadetraining step, everything is ok, traincasecade is run.

it seem to be size 24x24 is a default size of sample and it still remain. and i seem to be cannot config it in file .bat (i write command in file bat and click file bat to run)

And one thing i see in command window in above picture that: -precalcValBufSize and -precalcIdxBufSize still remain default value 1024. No change with -w -h -precalcValBufSize -precalcIdxBufSize.

So what problem with it, i don't understand why don't i choose size of sample for train. I just can use size 24x24, all size other always give error "Assertion failed <_img.row*_img.height == vecSize> in CvcascadeImageReader...pla pla"

Please help me to solve this problem. So many thank to you

Comment: Please include the full text of the error message you're getting. It will allow others to identify and fix your problem.

Comment: Hello Aurelius, Full text of error message is show in picture.